# Open Source Java Optimizer + Tutorial

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization

I am looking for an easy to use java solver for quadratic programming with quadratic constraints (QPQC).
While looking for two days now I found those three libraries:

- [jOptimizer](http://www.joptimizer.com/)
- [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/)
- Apache Commons Math (see: commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/)

However I couldn't find any easy to follow and complete tutorial (yet Im a beginner in Java and in using external libraries).

Are there any tutorials for newbies on how to use any of them?
Are there other open source / free to use Java Otpimizer/solver for quadratic programming with quadratic constraints?

EDIT 1#:

In Commons Math there you have only 1 unknown variable in the example as x, I try to solve an equation to all of its unknown ones. I guess I need much more time to get behind the implementation of this..

In short I'd like to solve a multivariable nonlinear objective equation with mixed (equality and inequality) constraints.

EDIT #2:
In addition is there any information about how these solvers scale?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: You want examples - whats wrong with the ones in their docs - 30seconds of searching gave: http://www.joptimizer.com/qcQuadraticProgramming.html

Comment: I already studied the examples given of the three pages. I was in hope of another examples or demos on a maybe well known website that could help me out. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Michael this is a specific question with references to existing tools and I don't think it is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you have some documentation on [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/optimization.html) for quadratic problems.

Answer (score 0):

Another open source Java optimizer that can handle quadratic constraints: [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) (Apache License)

Here's [a video of a simple tennis scheduling example with a quadratic fairness constraint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB2CxfLhHG4).

Comment: Are your variables integer numbers or decimal numbers? For integer numbers, OptaPlanner 6 should work well, although you might need to a custom `Move`. And you'll probably want to use `6.1.0.Beta1` or higher to take advantage of `ValueRangeFactory`.
For decimals variable numbers, I am less confident if metaheuristics are the right tool for the job: further experimentation is needed.

Comment: Thank you, optaPlanner looks friendly and promising. In fact my variables should be decimal numbers, but maybe starting with an integer representation will me forrce to dig deeper into my problem at first. I'll try this optimizer asap.